# Create event timeline from google sheets data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got 1 Google sheet (called DATA) with 3 columns (Start Date, End Date, Event Name) and then another Google sheet (called SCHEDULE) with 1 column of sequential dates (06/01/2018, 06/02/2018, etc).

I want to create a script that will read the Start Date and End Date from the DATA sheet and then creates a box (color-fills the corresponding cells) that spans the date range on the Schedule sheet. I know a fair amount of javascript, but I really don't even know where to start here. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You’re going to want to familiarize yourself with [Google Apps Script for Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). This will provide comfort and familiarity with the object model and how to recourse through ranges. I would probably loop through the Schedule sheet, and for each date in the schedule, loop through the data sheet row by row. For each iteration in the inner loop:

1. Convert all three date strings (1 on schedule and 2 on data) into [JS date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).
2. Knowing that Date.parse() returns an integer of milliseconds, check it schedule date between data dates.
3. If yes, color the box?

Does that work?

Comment: This a really helpful start! Thank you so much, @Tony-D!